# Unit of expression or expressions?

Tags: grammar

Considering the sentence

"A sentence is a grammatically independent unit of expression(s),"

Which one is correct?

"an independent unit of expressions"

or

"an independent unit of expression"?

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail in your question please. Like what are you trying to say, the context, etc. Is this something you are writing or did you read it somewhere? If you elaborate, it will be easier for us to understand and give you good answers.

Answer (score 1):

"a unit of expression" is the correct one.

Other examples include "unit of energy", "unit of mass", "unit of speech", ...

You can make such a phrase plural by adding "s" to the word "unit", as in "two different units of mass".